# Docker PHP sqlsrv_connect to docker mssql instance

Tags: php, sql-server, docker

I'm trying to get my PHP docker container connect to my docker mssql container but I am getting a network error.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => HYT00
        [SQLSTATE] => HYT00
        [1] => 0
        [code] => 0
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 08001
        [SQLSTATE] => 08001
        [1] => 10057
        [code] => 10057
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 08001
        [SQLSTATE] => 08001
        [1] => 10057
        [code] => 10057
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
    )
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
version: "3"

services:
  php:
    container_name: php
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php

  mssql:
    container_name: mssql
    build: 
      context: ./docker/mssql
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
```

I can connect to the SQL instance via SQL Server Management studio but I am failing to connect via PHP. Here are my connection details:

```
$serverName = "localhost"; 
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$database, "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"Password@", "CharacterSet"=>'UTF-8');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Comment: Docker containers are essentially their own little Linux VMs, so from a networking perspective `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1` all refer to the php container itself. Since you're using a Docker composition, which will have DNS running to provide lookups amongst the containers in the composition, have you tried `$serverName = "mssql";`?

Comment: I see. Thanks @AlwaysLearning! I was a little confused since I was connecting with "localhost" on SQL Server Management Studio. Changing the server name has worked. I'm still getting errors but I can work through this

Comment: SSMS isn't running inside a Docker container, though, is it? It's running on the Docker host. Since the composition publishes the mssql container's port on the host with `ports: - "1433:1433"` SSMS, running on the host, is actually able to connect to localhost:1433.

Comment: Nope it isn't. It's running locally on my machine, I just connect to localhost